# how to add table of contents to doxygen generated html file?

Tags: markdown, doxygen, tableofcontents

I have a C-project documented with doxygen and want to add a table of contents that shows the sections and subsections. I tried the `\tableofcontents` and the `[TOC]` as described in the doxygen manual, but nothing happens. Here is a small example:

```
/***********************************//**
 * \file        Bsp.c
 * \brief       example
 *
 * \tableofcontents
 *
 * \section sec1 section 1
 * blabla
 *
 * \section sec2 section 2
 * blabla
 *
 * \subsection ssec21 subsection 21
 * blabla
 ***********************************/



/***********************************//**
 * \brief   
 *
 * \section sec1func funcsection 1
 * blabla
 ***********************************/
void func() 
{

}
```

Here is what I get in html:

[link to output of example](http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/doxygenhtml6hlstapf92.png)

What do I do wrong? Thanks in advance for every hint!

Comment: On which page were you expecting the table of contents? Because placed this way it will appear on the documentation page for the file Bsp.c.

Comment: @ John: this is exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdtableofcontents) for doxygen says, that `@tableofcontents` only works on extra pages (`@page`, `@mainpage`), not in the regular documentation blocks.

You can still build your own table of contents using `@ref` and a bit of html (though it isn't as nice as using the builtin command).

Comment: ok, that's what _This command only works inside related page documentation and not in other documentation blocks..._ means then. I've got the wrong end of the stick. I thought it means that I can't include sections and subsections contained in other files (that are generated on different html-pages). Now I understand :) Thanks John!

Comment: For future readers: `@tableofcontents` and `[TOC]` also work in external markdown documents. Commenting because this page is the first one you get trying to figure it out, so might be helpful to someone.